# Chaning the path of your Python in terminal

Tags: python, macos, selenium, terminal

I've noticed that some of my scripts aren't working when I run them in the terminal. For example, I get this error message when I try to run Selenium:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/Moltas/Documents/Pythons/Coockie.py", line 1, in <module>
      from selenium import webdriver
    ImportError: No module named selenium
```

So I did some research and noticed that the problem could be that terminal uses a different version of python than the one I normally use. So in Python, I found out that terminal uses python 2.7.10 while I use 3.6.1.

**How do you change the path that terminal uses for Python?**

Comment: You might try using `python3` or `python3.6` as the program name.

Comment: Thank you please write that as an answear cuz you're a fu sorry no swearing, ehrm genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the Python 3.6 interpreter directly as:

```
python3.6
```

Alternatively, if this is the only python 3 installed, you can also likely do:

```
python3
```